# Angular & Spring: How to load an external page, without exposing the URL?

Tags: html, angular, spring, rest

This might be an odd question, so I'm trying to explain my issue as well as I can. 
I have a frontend application, that has to load an iframe-content from another page. However, the frontend application isn't allowed to simply call URL of the to-be integrated application but instead by a sort of proxy address. Even URL Parameters that allow changes on the iframe-content are supposed to be run through the Spring Backend first, which calls the particular page and then returns it to the frontend.

What did I do? At first, I tried to create a pretty barebones REST call. Keep in mind, I'm not very knowledgable when it comes to Spring

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/include-content", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public ResponseEntity<String> getIFrameContent() {
    String server1 = <page_in_frame>;

    RestTemplate rest;
    HttpHeaders headers;

    rest = new RestTemplate();
    headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Type", "text/html");
    headers.add("Accept", "*/*");

    HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>("", headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = rest.exchange(server1, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class);

    return responseEntity;
}
```

Getting a response from it looked fine, at least with a REST-Client for a quick test. So I went on with my frontend. I kept it as basic as possible there as well.

For the HTML Template

```
<div id="main-content" class="container-fluid">
  <iframe id="iframe-content" frameborder="0" style="width: 90%; height: 700px">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

And for the ts I created a method that works like this...

```
  redirectTo() {
    this.httpClient.get("http://localhost:8080/api/include-content", {responseType: "text"}).subscribe(data => {
      this.redirectData = data;
    }, (error) => {
      this.errorService.showError(error)
    }, () => {
      let iFrame = document.getElementById("powerBIFrame");
      iFrame['src'] = 'data:text/html,' + encodeURIComponent(this.redirectData);
    });
  }
```

What I didn't consider in this case is, that I don't get any resources back. I just get a static page without styling and/or functionality. Clicking any on the links just creates an empty page. I could only conclude that my approach is inherently flawed and that I require (perhaps?) some sort of proxy functionality on my backend?

Answer (score 1):

You will *have* to expose a url to the frontend if you're using an iframe as it needs a source to load in this case.

If you're wanting to use a backend generated output (spring) you can simply point to the localhost/whatever (like you have now) and set it as the `src`. This will work and is trivial.

I would inject the response payload into the DOM rather than passing it as the `src` attribute especially if it's going to potentially be a large payload (as is the case with power bi views).

Comment: This seems to make an awful lot of sense. I might actually break the code in the effort of encoding it before I add it as a src. I'll try to use your suggestion when I get home! But just because curiosity struck again, is it generally frowned upon accessing the DOM src attribute directly?

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't seem to quite work. The type of error changed. But now it is expecting the assets of the page to be in my backend folder and shows for all assets an 404 error.

Comment: You're going to have to proxy the assets request(s) accordingly.

Comment: Is there a specific way to do this in spring? I mean, what's so different from calling a web page via URL on the Browser and returning the web response like in the code?

Comment: If I understand correctly, when you load the url in the iframe that page has assets like images/scripts/etc.. and this is your problem right? If that's the case you could use a proxy to proxy these requests to the right directory(s). or you will need to bundle your assets with your spring app and let it serve them from there (spring uses it's own web server container like tomcat).

Comment: Exactly. Only the HTML is received, but lacking the resources. I seem to lack a fundamental understanding regarding web-requests in general. Sadly, I can't bundle the assets in my project as it comes from an external source and is meant to kept that way. Do you perhaps know of an article or something similar that is mentioning a similar issue?